# How do I get to paint the strip?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to color the strip. The function is $y = \frac{1}{x}$
I can to draw, but I can't color the strip\;\

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$x$};
   \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
   \draw[scale=1.5,domain=0.35:4,smooth, variable=\x,black, ultra thick] plot ({\x},{1/(\x)});
\draw[dashed] (3,0)--(3,0.75);
\draw[dashed] (0,0.75)--(3,0.75);
    \node at (-0.5,0.75){$\frac{1}{b}$};
    \node at (3,-0.3){$b$};
        \node at (1,-0.3){$a$};
  \node at (-0.5,2.2) {$\frac{1}{a}$};
\draw[dashed] (1,0)--(1,2.2);
\draw[dashed] (0,2.2)--(1,2.2);
\node at (1,2.2) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (3,0.75) {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with the `mfpic` package, a LaTeX interface for MetaPost (and METAFONT) for whom it may interest.

The filling is achieved by the following instruction

```
\gfill[.5(red+white)]\btwnfcn{1, 3, .1}{0}{f(x)}
```

`\btwnfcn` produces the closed path formed by two functions (here `0` and `f(x)`) and verticals lines (here of equations `x=1` and `x=3`), which is then filled.

Note than since the function path is scaled in the OP's example by a factor of 1.5, I have preferred to define `f(x)` as equal to `2.25/x` instead of `1/x`. It produces the same path than with the scaling, and it is much easier to handle it this way.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[metapost, mplabels, truebbox]{mfpic}
  \mfpverbtex{%&latex
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}}
  \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
  \opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mfpic}[1]{-1}{7}{-1}{5}
    \fdef{f}{x}{2.25/x}
    \gfill[.5(red+white)]\btwnfcn{1, 3, .1}{0}{f(x)}
    \dashed\lines{(1, 0), (1, f(1)), (0, f(1))}
    \dashed\lines{(3, 0), (3, f(3)), (0, f(3))}
    \doaxes{xy}
    \penwd{1.2bp}
    \function{.5, 6, .1}{f(x)}
    \tlpointsep{3bp}
    \tlabels{[tr]{origin}{$O$} [tc]{(\xmax, 0)}{$x$} [cr]{(0, \ymax)}{$y$}
      [tc]{(1, 0)}{$a$} [tc]{(3, 0)}{$b$} 
      [cr]{(0, f(1))}{$\dfrac{1}{a}$} [cr]{(0, f(3))}{$\dfrac{1}{b}$}}
  \end{mfpic}
  \closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

To by run with (PDF)LaTeX, then MetaPost, then (PDF)LaTeX again. Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just do a fill under the curve.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [red!50, domain=1:3, variable=\x]
  (1, 0)
  -- plot ({\x}, {2.2/(\x)})
  -- (3, 0)
  -- cycle;      \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$x$};
   \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
   \draw[scale=1.5,domain=0.35:4,smooth, variable=\x,black, ultra thick] plot ({\x},{1/(\x)});
\draw[dashed] (3,0)--(3,0.75);
\draw[dashed] (0,0.75)--(3,0.75);
    \node at (-0.5,0.75){$\frac{1}{b}$};
    \node at (3,-0.3){$b$};
        \node at (1,-0.3){$a$};
  \node at (-0.5,2.2) {$\frac{1}{a}$};
\draw[dashed] (1,0)--(1,2.2);
\draw[dashed] (0,2.2)--(1,2.2);
\node at (1,2.2) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (3,0.75) {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]